# Dropdown for new properties on Angular UI

Tags: c#, abp

I'm working with Abp framework with Angular UI, adding a new prop with a prop contributor to identity forms, it works well it is sending the extra properties correctly with the typehead proptype:

```
const timeZoneProp = new FormProp<IdentityUserDto>({
    type: ePropType.Typeahead,
    name: 'TimeZoneId',
    displayName: '::TimeZone',
    isExtra: true,
    id: 'TimeZoneId',
    autocomplete: 'off',
    validators: () => [Validators.required],
    options: data => {
      const service = data.getInjected(TimeZoneService);
      return service
        .getList()
        .pipe(
          map(
            response =>
              response.items?.map(
                item =>
                  ({ key: item.description, value: item.id } as Option<any>)
              ) || []
          )
        );
    }
  });

  propList.addByIndex(timeZoneProp, 6);
```

This send two extra properties:

```
{[TimeZoneId, 02a3c132-d7b7-78ed-776e-3a0b3293827b]}
{[TimeZoneId_Text, (UTC-08:00) Pacific Time (US and Canada) America/Los_Angeles]}
```

It is working as expected, if I change the input into another timezone it got changed successfully, but now I want to change typehead to Enum to display a dropdown as:

```
type: ePropType.Enum,
...
```

If I change the value of the selected input the extra property does not change the `TimeZoneId_Text` property it only changes the `TimeZoneId` in the request. Why is the change not reflected on the Text property?